# Can't connect TableView @IBOutlet to ViewController in Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I am building an app in which I want to press an annotation button and a `TableViewCell` will pop up. The problem is, when I try to create an `@IBOutlet` with control+ drag, to `ViewController`, it doesn't work. Also if I simply write the code : `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` on `ViewController`, when I run the app and hit the button, it crashes. What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by ' when I try to create an @IBOutlet with control+ drag, to ViewController, it doesn't work'.

Comment: Do you confirm the xib file's class is the same as your .h or .m file's class

Comment: When I control drag from Main.Storyboard, it doesn't do anything. Which means it doesn't connect

Comment: did you get it solved? i'm stuck too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chris,refer this image.Maybe it helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Although I am using Storyboard and I think you can't have both Placeholders and a Storyboard, you have to choose either when you start a project

Comment: This helped me. New to iOS swift development and was stuck on this error for hours. Thank You sir.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the given class in the Identity Inspector matches your class name.

[image]

Comment: Yep, I tried that, But it is not the same identity, and when i change it, it changes back. It is messed up but I don't know in which part. 
I have the ViewController and a separate class "TableViewController that I link with with TableViewController. Apart from that, nothing else that could affect it